# Couchbase and GeoSpatial data

Tags: couchbase, geojson

Can't find documentation/howtos/examples for using Geo Views in couchbase.

**Simplified** task: my document looks like:

```
{
 x:10,
 y:15,
 color:"RED"
}
```

and I need to find all **BLUE** points in square

```
{top:1,left:1,right:34,bottom:77}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of how to perform a geospatial view in the [Couchbase Java SDK Developer Guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4/index.html#experimental-spatial-views).

The main things to be aware of:

- Your emitted documents (i.e. `map()` function result) needs to conform to the [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) specification.
- (In the Java SDK at least) you need to use the [`getSpatialView()`](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-java-client-1.4.3/index.html) method to query it.

Answer (score 5):

Currently Couchbase does only support 2D queries, that means that you would need to filter by the color on the client side.

I'm currently working on having support for n dimensions.

Comment: An answer by the creator himself -- the wonders of open source and Stack Overflow.

Comment: I realize real coordinates in GeoJSON are doubles. Does couch support string (binary) "coordinates" out of double range. I mean something like: point{x:'00FF000000000A00A0', y:10}. In this case I can "pack" coor information into some coordinate....